# Adding to Filters collection in Kendo Grid: C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to unit test filters on a Kendo Grid, but I when I add a filter the filter collection is null.  How do I set up the filters so they are not null when I add to the collection?

Here is the relevant code.

```
    var kendoDataRequest = new DataSourceRequest();
    var filter = new FilterDescriptor {Member = "test", Value = "test"};
    kendoDataRequest.Filters.Add(filter);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var kendoDataRequest = new DataSourceRequest();
var filter = new FilterDescriptor {Member = "test", Value = "test"};

kendoDataRequest.Filters = new List<IFilterDescriptor>();

kendoDataRequest.Filters.Add(filter);
```